# Eliminate zones that a line is nowhere near

Tags: c#, .net, linq, geometry

I have a map that has some DeadZones (Areas that cannot be reached) plotted on it.

There comes a point in the flow of my application where I need to check if a line is reachable on this map.

Now, my line intersection code is pretty solid, but I am having trouble figuring out how to limit the number of dead zones that need to be checked against, as some of them will be the other side of the map.

Now a Dead Zone is just a `List<Point>` where a `Point` is an x and y, both of type `double` and my line is just 2 seperate Points that describe the beginning and the end of the line.

So, where I am calling this and processing against all Deadzone, this is what I was doing:

```
DeadZones.All(dz => !FastPolygons.DoesLineIntersectPolygon(point1, point2, dz.Polygon));
```

To start with, I thought I could use the MaxX and MaxY from the deadzone to eliminate ones that are far away, but if both of the points sit outside the deadzone, then all of them would still be processed and it would require one of the points at each end of the line to actually sit in the deadzone in order for that deadzone to be eliminated.

I wrote a method that I could use in a `Where` in my linq statement to attempt this before I realized how this wouldn't work. This is what I attempted

```
private static bool ZoneCouldNotOverlap(Point point, Zone zone)
{
    return (zone.MaxX < point.X || zone.MaxY < point.Y) || (zone.MinX > point.X || zone.MinY > point.Y);
}
```

and then the Linq statement became this:

```
DeadZones.Where(x=> ZoneCouldNotOverlap(point1,x) || ZoneCouldNotOverlap(point2,x)).All(dz => !FastPolygons.DoesLineIntersectPolygon(point1, point2, dz.Polygon));
```

So I've got to this point where I can eliminate a huge portion of the map, and therefore not process the deadzones in the portion of the map that I am not interested in, but I can't seem to realize how to do this in my Linq statement. Any help is massively appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm also very welcoming for the best suggestions on how to apply parellelization here too

Comment: I'm currently in the process of making a line a struct rather than just 2 points, so I can have access to the Min and Max for each of the axes and have an idea of something to try. I'll update my question if things don't work out with this idea

Comment: Don't you have to verify that both points are not on opposite sides of the zone?  So you could use the min and max x and y of the zone as a bonding box and then check to make sure that both points are to the right, left, above or below that box to exclude that zone?

Comment: @juharr that is what my thinking is with the solution I am trying now. Making line a struct makes that easier by giving me the MinX and MaxX and the same for Y as properties

Comment: I'm not sure you need to know the min and max of the line segment,  just that both points lie on the same side of the zone.  A line struct or class would be a good idea in any case.

Comment: @juharr you are right, but having the min and max of the line allows me to easily say, is this entire line outside the polygon on any side. Just makes it all look cleaner. I'm testing it now, see if it has made an improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this knocked ~30 seconds off the time it takes to process through 5000 iterations, so it seems a sufficient answer.

What I did was create a `struct` Called line to use in place of the pair of points.

That looks like this:

```
 public struct Line
 {
     public List<Point> Points { get; private set; }
     public double MaxX { get; private set; }
     public double MinX { get; private set; }
     public double MinY { get; private set; }
     public double MaxY { get; private set; }

     public Line(Point start, Point end) : this()
     {
         Points = new List<Point>();
         Points.AddRange(new[] {start, end});
         var xs = Points.Select(p => p.X);
         var ys = Points.Select(p => p.Y);
         MaxX = xs.Max();
         MinX = xs.Min();
         MaxY = ys.Max();
         MinY = ys.Min();
     }
 }
```

Then I used that in a new Method called `ZoneCouldNotOverlapLine()` and that looks like this:

```
 private static bool ZoneCouldNotOverlapLine(Line line, Zone zone)
 {
     return (line.MinX > zone.MaxX || line.MaxX < zone.MinX) && (line.MaxY < zone.MinY || line.MinY > zone.MaxY);
 }
```

Which in turn, I used in my Linq statement like so:

```
DeadZones.Where(z=> !ZoneCouldNotOverlapLine(line,z))
.All(dz => !FastPolygons.DoesLineIntersectPolygon(point1, point2, dz.Polygon));
```

This is effectivley saying only look at deadzones where the entire line is not on a single side of the zone. There are a few more places in my code where optimizations like this would be useful, and working through this will have helped me no end to getting those issues solved too.